# django parler create test objects

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-parler

I have models that have translatable fields using Django Parler and now I am trying to create objects for unit testing. Here is an example model that I have

```
class Federation(TranslatableModel):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        name = models.CharField('name', max_length=50)
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='federation_creator')
    updater = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='federation_updater')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name;
```

Now I want to create objects for testing during setUp phase of test case:

```
 Federation.objects.create(...)
```

but I don't know how to create objects with translatable fields.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in the way the Parler documentation suggests throughout:

```
f = Federation()

f.set_current_language('en')
f.name = 'The British'

f.set_current_language('fr')
f.name = 'Les rosbifs'

f.save()
```

But you can also do:

```
f = Federation.objects.language('en').create(
    name='The British',
)

f.set_current_language('fr')
f.name = 'Les rosbifs'

f.save()
```

which is what you're asking about and is more elegant, especially if you only have one language version to create.

I discovered the `language('en')` method [here](https://github.com/django-parler/django-parler/blob/master/parler/managers.py#L34-L39).